# How to get element value from JSON object and first convert it to HTML and then to String

Tags: javascript, json, dom

Hi i´m getting a JSON string from an XMLHttpRequest which I fist convert into a JavaScript Object:

```
response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

One of the JSON element values is a string which represents a script tag with a noscript tag like that (output shows console.log(response.ad.con);):

```
<SCRIPT language='JavaScript1.1' SRC="https://ad.doubleclick.net/ddm/adj/N378.150781.4704472308521/B5632202.128522416;sz=300x250;ord=[timestamp];dc_lat=;dc_rdid=;tag_for_child_directed_treatment=?"></SCRIPT><NOSCRIPT><A HREF="https://ad.doubleclick.net/ddm/jump/N378.150781.4704472308521/B5632202.128522416;sz=300x250;ord=[timestamp]?"><IMG SRC="https://ad.doubleclick.net/ddm/ad/N378.150781.4704472308521/B5632202.128522416;sz=300x250;ord=timestamp];dc_lat=;dc_rdid=;tag_for_child_directed_treatment=?" BORDER=0 WIDTH=300 HEIGHT=250 ALT="Advertisement"></A></NOSCRIPT>
```

I now wanna get the string which is in the SRC element of the script tag.
How can I do that? I think i´m lost in conversion...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is this string just the script tag, or does it have the other tags too?

Comment: Wouldn't a regex do it? I wouldn't normally recomend regex to extract stuff from HTML, but in this case it seems you know the structure and know you just need the *first* instance of a `SRC`, so perhaps something like `/ SRC="([^"]+)"/`.

Comment: Usually the string looks like that. In special cases there might be more than one script tag. but the relevant src is always in the first script tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to parse HTML strings, just like you would JSON etc. and then just get the attribute with DOM methods

```
var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

var parser   = new DOMParser();
var doc      = parser.parseFromString(response.propertyWithHtml, "text/html");

var src      = doc.querySelector('script').getAttribute('src');
```

Comment: [Just note you need a decently modern browser for this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: Thanks, that did it for me. Now i need to dynamically add a script tag with this source to a div element in my HTML page. The script must load dynamically as well. but i guess that´s for another question ^^

Answer (score 1):

if you use jQuery,
try this

```
$('<SCRIPT language="JavaScript1.1" SRC="https://ad.doubleclick.net/ddm/adj/N378.150781.4704472308521/B5632202.128522416;sz=300x250;ord=[timestamp];dc_lat=;dc_rdid=;tag_for_child_directed_treatment=?"></SCRIPT><NOSCRIPT><A HREF="https://ad.doubleclick.net/ddm/jump/N378.150781.4704472308521/B5632202.128522416;sz=300x250;ord=[timestamp]?"><IMG SRC="https://ad.doubleclick.net/ddm/ad/N378.150781.4704472308521/B5632202.128522416;sz=300x250;ord=timestamp];dc_lat=;dc_rdid=;tag_for_child_directed_treatment=?" BORDER=0 WIDTH=300 HEIGHT=250 ALT="Advertisement"></A></NOSCRIPT>').attr("SRC")
```

Comment: jQuery isn't in the tags.

Comment: I think the author just wanna to get the text in the SRC attribute